# APL/APLX - Splitting a string

Tags: arrays, string-conversion, apl

I have a single string (the result from reading in a paragraph of text) that I'd like to split into an array of words. I'd be splitting the string on every space. This seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to find out a way to accomplish this.

It's worth noting that I'm using APLX, so I do have the option of importing a Ruby function, but I'd much rather stick to APL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many different way to tackle this. Most often I use the following dfn in [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com):

```
penclose←{⎕ML←3 ⋄ ⍺←↑,⍵ ⋄ (~⍵∊⍺)⊂,⍵ } ⍝ separator as ⍺ or ⍵[1]
```

I'm not sure whether APLX has dfns, so a more "traditional" style would be:

```
∇ R←penclose R;a
   ⍝ Partitioned enclose of text vector with separator in R[1]
   ⍝ ⎕ML←3  ⍝ Dyalog-specific to make ⊂ APL2-compatible...
 a←1↑R ⋄ R←(~R∊a)⊂R
∇
```

Comment: In your APLX definition, what does the comma operator do? In my experiments with GNU APL, it seems to suffice to do `R←(~R∊a)⊂R`

Comment: Thanks for asking! It was intended as a safety measure against the RANK ERROR you'd as a result of calling `penclose''`or `penclose'x'` which are not plausible, but more likely as a result of `penclose bool/string` - but while the dfn was safe, my translation into traditional style did not properly take care of that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: In Dyalog you can just use ⊆ instead of ⊂, without setting ⎕ML.

Comment: Yep, that's right. It was added in v16 ( https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Nest ) - and I probably did not want to use such cutting-edge features then ;)